# How I can hide scrollbar at terminal Xubuntu 14.04?

Tags: xubuntu, scrollbar

With dark terminal white scrollbar looks bad.

Comment: You could use ubuntu overlay scrollbars but that would apply it to all system apps.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can disable the scrollbar completely (still able to scroll with mousewheel) from the Terminal Preferences.

1. Open Preferences (Edit Menu-> Preferences, or Right Click -> Preferences)
2. Select the "General" tab.
3. Change "Scrollbar is:" to "Disabled".

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Oh, thank you. Just in preferences - I had to explore settings myself.